# Build and install latest OpenSSL v1.1.0c

Tags: build, openssl

What I did:

1. Login into Linux m/c
2. run command: su
3. run command: wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0c.tar.gz
4. run command: gzip –d openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
5. run command: tar -xvf openssl-1.1.0c.tar.gz
6. run command: cd openssl-1.1.0c
7. run command: ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
8. run command: gmake clean depend
9. run command: gmake
10. run command: gmake install
11. run command: cd /usr/local/ssl/bin
12. run command: ./openssl version

**Expected result:** OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016

**Actual result:** OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009

**Why is the OpenSSL is showing different version? and how to fix this?**

Comment: 12. `./openssl version`

Comment: fixed the typo in the question

Comment: Please post the result of `ls -al /usr/local/ssl/bin`. You might consider a quick reboot, but that usually fixes the the problem on OS X (I've never seen it apply to Linux). Your `./config` line should include `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib`. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Followed the same steps for openSSL-1.0.2j.tar.gz and its reporting the desired version.

Comment: output for ls -al /usr/local/ssl/bin  <br/> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5104 Dec 26 05:03 c_rehash <br/> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 669314 Dec 26 05:03 openssl <br/>